# How to extract this one frame from simulation?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

[image: Bledner Cloth simulation]

Plus, how to fix that cloth penetration through the mesh beneath it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Just hit the APPLY button to the cloth modifier on the object. Then the operator stack will freeze your desired frame.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! it had no idea that it would be that simple.